# Javascript js file is not picked up while running index.html file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am beginner for React and trying my first React program, and writing the basic export function and print one image on browser. However it is not working as expected. Can please guide me, its my first JS/React program.

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>First Component</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>First Component</h1>
<script type="module" src="./index.js" > </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
export default function Profile() {
  return (
      <img
          src="https://i.imgur.com/MK3eW3Am.jpg"
          alt="Katherine Johnson"
      />
  )
}
```

Edit :
index.html and index.js both are at same directory level.

While I run this I get below error in my console for export keyword
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'**

Update :
While I give under index.html script type as module it resolved export error. Now it started giving below error for first "<" tag.
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'**

Comment: You need Babel to use React components directly in your HTML page. See the [Try React locally](https://react.dev/learn/installation#try-react-locally) instructions for a working example

Comment: ...that isn't a Javascript file. Do you have a process set up to compile your React code to Javascript? Also, is that file in the same directory as index.html?

Comment: Personally, I recommend using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) to quickly get a project up and running... `npm create vite@latest my-react-app -- --template react`

Comment: @JaredSmith, yeah both are at same level, and while I run the index.html I am getting Syntax error at export keyword. I have updated the question.

Comment: @pargrng "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" that's what I meant about your file not being Javascript. That's JSX, and the browser can't handle it. There are a number of compilers that compile that down to regular Javascript function calls. I strongly recommend using a app scaffolder that handles some of these details for you while you are learning. Then once your more comfortable you can go back and learn the details they handle for you.